# Am I stuck in a boy band?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

By that I mean, am I stuck with Gladiolus, Ignis, and Prompto as my party members? It's not that I dislike being around them, but after being in a party with Iris and Aranea, I realized they were quite helpful. But unfortunately, good things never last and they left my party.

Is there/will there be a way (after I complete the story, perhaps?) to have people like Aranea or Iris join my party? Or am I stuck in my bro squad?

Comment: Yep, you are stuck in a boy band where the leader has daddy issues.  Enjoy!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you are in a boy band. Occasionally, you will be able to recruit some backup dancers but they are not permanent.

Hajime Tabata, the director of Final Fantasy 15, said the goal is to leave the male characters alone on their road trip so they can be more comfortable around each other.